# Scope of RestController and Controller in Spring

Tags: spring, scope, controller, javabeans

What should be the scope of Controller and RestController in a Spring application? The default behavior if being Singleton. But will not having single bean cross over the request/responses from multiple clients, as our Controller will call some other bean (say @Service) which handles user specific request (like fetching user details from a DB or from another REST/SOAP service).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

Option 1 - In your service classes, ensure that you do not save any request specific details in instance variables. Instead pass them around as method arguments.

Ex:

The below code will corrupt the value stored in userId if there are simultaneous requests.

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    String userId;

    public void processRequest(String userId, String orderId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        // Some code
        process(orderId);
    }

    public void process(String orderId) {
        // code that uses orderId
    }

}
```

While, the following code is safe.

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    private String userId;

    public void processRequest(String userId, String orderId) {
        // Some code
        process(userId, orderId);
    }

    public void process(String userId, String orderId) {
        // code that uses userId and orderId
    }

}
```

Option 2:

You can save request specific data in request scoped beans and inject them in your singletons. Spring creates a proxy for the injected request scoped beans and proxies calls to the bean associated with the current request.

```
@RequestScoped
class UserInfo {
}


@Service
class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    public void process(String orderId) {
        // It is safe to invoke methods of userInfo here. The calls will be passed to the bean associated with the current request.
    }
}
```